# How can I permanently show sidebar in a SwiftUI NavigationView or SplitNavigationView exactly like the Apple Settings App on iPad?

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationsplitview

I am trying to display a two column NavigationView in my app exactly like the settings on the iPad.  With no way to collapse the sidebar on an iPad.  I would have thought using a NavigationView with DoubleColumnStyle would work but it doesn't and it's deprecated.  I can use a NavigationSplitView like before to control the initial look however the user is still able to collapse the navigation sidebar.

I thought there would be a simple solution to this but have been looking for a while and haven't found any approach that works.

So far I have the following:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @State private var columnVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.doubleColumn
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here both the icon in the top left to hide the sidebar is generated automatically and also dragging the sidebar to the left closes it.

Comment: I have come across BalancedNavigationSplitViewStyle() which shows both sidebar and detail together but unfortunately it still allows the sidebar to collapse.

Comment: Settings doesn't support multitasking split view because there isn't enough room for both columns) so I guess they didn't want to make that possible in SwiftUI. I think it was possible with the old `NavigationView` by overriding the size class with `.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)` but I just checked and that has no effect on the new NavigationSplitView.

Answer (score 3):

Add add `navigationSplitViewStyle` balanced and also change `columnVisibility` to all

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @State private var columnVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent clicking the Sidebar collapse icon to hide the sidebar.

Comment: did anyone get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to prevent sidebar from collapsing, you can try **.navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)** modifier. Here is a full demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var columnVisibility =
    NavigationSplitViewVisibility.doubleColumn
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility){
            List(0..<30){ i in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Details of \(i)")) {
                    Text("id:\(i)")
                }

            } .navigationBarHidden(true)

        } detail: {
            Text("Choose an item from the content")
            
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced) // this
    }
}
```

[image: Prevent sidebar from collapsing]